# Overridding default batch size in Mongodb connection

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm looking for some code to override the default batch size of the Mongodb cursor in java.

Similar to one achieved by:

```
com.mongodb.Mongo mClient = new com.mongodb.MongoClient(context.MongoDBServerName, context.MongoDBPort);

com.mongodb.DB db = mClient .getDB(context.MongoDatabase);

db.collection.find().batch_size(40)
```

But I want it to be done in the db connection object itself instead of during the find query.

So that I could use the same for all queries.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, there is no other place to configure this batchSize value. Batch size can be configured only at cursor level.

In your code, batchSize method name is wrong. It should be as follows

```
db.users.find().batchSize(10)
```

Comment: Actually find part of code in my application is non editable sort of api. Thats why searching for a solution to change it in connection level

Comment: In my application i can't edit this part of code db.users.find().batchSize(10), all I can edit is connection object that's y searching for an option to do it in connection level